# Videos in long Flatlist crashes the app and having poor performance

Tags: react-native, youtube, babeljs, react-native-flatlist, react-native-video

**Topic**: Video Flatlist in React Native. (Normal Videos / YouTube Videos)

Any one will be displayed according to the array data simultaneously. So it will be a long flatlist containing two types of video.

Sometimes many onPress event doesn't work due to performance issue

**Major Issues:**

1. App crashes when scrolling bottom to top
2. Performance is very poor

Above two are the major issue need to solve. Are there any ways to solve these issues?

What solutions can I try to improve `Flatlist` performance and to solve Video Flatlist crashing issue?

Below is my code in *App.js*

```
import React from "react";
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    SafeAreaView,
    FlatList,
    TouchableWithoutFeedback,
    Dimensions
} from "react-native";

import Video from "react-native-video";
import ProgressBar from "react-native-progress/Bar";
import YouTube from 'react-native-youtube';
import LightVideo from "./sample.mp4";

import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";

// console.disableYellowBox = true;
function secondsToTime(time) {
    return ~~(time / 60) + ":" + (time % 60 < 10 ? "0" : "") + time % 60;
}

const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
const height = width * 0.5625;


const list = [
    {
        'type': 'YouTube'
    },
    {
        'type': 'Normal'
    },
    {
        'type': 'YouTube'
    },
    {
        'type': 'Normal'
    },
    {
        'type': 'Normal'
    },
];


export default class RNVideo extends React.PureComponent {

    state = {
        video: [],
        duration: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        progress: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.player = [];
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.progress_state();
        this.duration_state();
        this.video_pause_state(false);
    }

    play_pause_button = (index) => {
        if (this.state.progress >= 1) {
            this.player[index].seek(0);
        }
        var statevisible = this.state.video;
        statevisible[index] = !statevisible[index];
        this.setState({
            video: statevisible
        });
        this.forceUpdate();
    };


    progress_bar_touch(e, index) {
        const position = e.nativeEvent.locationX;
        const progress = (position / 250) * this.state.duration[index];
        this.player[index].seek(progress);
    };

    handleProgress(progress, index) {
        var statevisible = this.state.progress;
        statevisible[index] = progress.currentTime / this.state.duration[index];
        this.setState({
            progress: statevisible
        });
        this.forceUpdate();
    };

    handleLoad(meta, index) {
        var statevisible = this.state.duration;
        statevisible[index] = meta.duration;
        this.setState({
            duration: statevisible
        });
        this.forceUpdate();
    };

    onViewableItemsChanged = async ({ viewableItems }) => {
        this.video_pause_state(true);
        if (viewableItems != '' && viewableItems != null) {
            var indexvalue = viewableItems[0]['index'];
            var statevisible = this.state.video;
            statevisible[indexvalue] = !statevisible[indexvalue];
            this.setState({
                video: statevisible
            });
            this.forceUpdate();
        }
    }


    // shouldComponentUpdate() {
    //   return false
    // }


    video_pause_state(value) {
        var statevisible = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            statevisible[i] = value;
        }
        this.setState({
            video: statevisible
        });
    }

    progress_state() {
        var statevisible = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            statevisible[i] = 0;
        }
        this.setState({
            progress: statevisible
        });
    }


    duration_state() {
        var statevisible = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            statevisible[i] = 0;
        }
        this.setState({
            duration: statevisible
        });
    }

    video_end(index) {
        var statevisible1 = this.state.duration;
        statevisible1[index] = 0;
        var statevisible2 = this.state.progress;
        statevisible2[index] = 0;
        this.setState({
            duration: statevisible1,
            progress: statevisible2
        });
        this.play_pause_button(index);
    }

    keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString()

    renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
        <>
            {item.type != 'YouTube' ?
                <>
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <View>
                            <Video
                                paused={this.state.video[index]}
                                muted={this.state.video[index]}
                                source={LightVideo}
                                // controls={true}
                                // repeat={true}
                                style={styles.videos}
                                resizeMode="cover"
                                onLoad={(meta) => this.handleLoad(meta, index)}
                                onProgress={(progress) => this.handleProgress(progress, index)}
                                onEnd={() => this.video_end(index)}
                                ref={(ref) => {
                                    this.player[index] = ref
                                }}
                            />
                            <View style={styles.controls}>
                                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={(event) => this.play_pause_button(index)}>
                                    <Icon name={!this.state.video[index] ? "pause" : "play"} size={30} color="#FFF" />
                                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={(event) => this.progress_bar_touch(event, index, this)}>
                                    <View>
                                        <ProgressBar
                                            progress={this.state.progress[index]}
                                            color="#FFF"
                                            unfilledColor="rgba(255,255,255,.5)"
                                            borderColor="#FFF"
                                            width={230}
                                            height={20}
                                        />
                                    </View>
                                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                                <Text style={styles.duration}>
                                    {secondsToTime(Math.floor(this.state.progress[index] * this.state.duration[index]))}
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </>

                :

                <>
                    <View style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
                        <YouTube
                            apiKey="YOUR_API_KEY"
                            videoId="YOUR_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID_FROM_URL"
                            play={this.state.video[index]}
                            style={styles.videos}
                        />
                    </View>
                </>
            }
        </>
    )

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <FlatList
                        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                        data={list}
                        renderItem={this.renderItem}
                        extraData={this.state}
                        onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
                        removeClippedSubviews={true}
                        maxToRenderPerBatch={3}
                        initialNumToRender={3}
                        legacyImplementation={true}
                    />
                </SafeAreaView>
            </>
        );
    }
}

const wid = "95%";
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginBottom: 60,
        marginTop: 60,
    },
    controls: {
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
        height: 48,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        position: "absolute",
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "space-around",
        width: wid,
        margin: 8,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
    },
    mainButton: {
        marginRight: 15,
    },
    duration: {
        color: "#FFF",
        marginLeft: 15,
    },
    videos: {
        width: wid,
        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
        borderRadius: 10,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        margin: 8,
        height
    },
});
```

### Update

I have come up with this final solution. But not able to do autoplay. Need ideas on this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import YouTube from 'react-native-youtube';
import { OptimizedFlatList } from 'react-native-optimized-flatlist'
import VideoPlayer from 'react-native-video-player';

const list = [
  {
    'type': 'Normal'
  },
  {
    'type': 'YouTube'
  },
  {
    'type': 'Normal'
  },
  {
    'type': 'Normal'
  },
  {
    'type': 'YouTube'
  },
  {
    'type': 'Normal'
  },
  {
    'type': 'Normal'
  },
  {
    'type': 'Normal'
  },
];

export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.player = [];

    this.state = {
      video: { width: undefined, height: undefined, duration: undefined },
      thumbnailUrl: undefined,
      videoUrl: undefined,
    };
  }

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString()

  renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
    <>
      {item.type != 'YouTube' ?
        <>
          <View style={styles.videos}>
            <VideoPlayer
              // autoplay
              // pauseOnPress
              video={{ uri: 'https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4', type: 'mp4' }}
              resizeMode={'cover'}
              ref={r => this.player[index] = r}
            />
          </View>
        </>
        :
        <>
          <View style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
            <YouTube
              apiKey="YOUR_API_KEY"
              videoId="3NQRhE772b0"
              style={{...styles.videos,...styles.videos1}}
            />
          </View>
        </>
      }
    </>
  )

  onViewableItemsChanged = async ({ viewableItems }) => {
    if (viewableItems != '' && viewableItems != null) {
      var indexvalue = viewableItems[0]['index'];
      indexvalue++;
      if (indexvalue != 1) {
        if (!this.player[indexvalue].state.isPlaying) {
          this.player[indexvalue].pause();
        } else {
          this.player[indexvalue].resume();
        }
      }
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <OptimizedFlatList
            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
            data={list}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            removeClippedSubviews={true}
            onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  videos: {
    width: "95%",
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
    borderRadius: 10,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    margin: 10,
    marginBottom: 20,
    marginTop: 20
  },
  videos1: {
    height: 250
  }
});
```

Comment: flatlist provide onEndReached you can add loadmore video with pagination

Comment: but the code I have given crashes only for 5 elements and the app freezes for few moments.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-snap-carousel use this with current index is equal to video then play otherwise pause so it will not take more load and also use pagination for videos first 4 then next 4 vidoe like this

Comment: okay. I will try this one. Can you also throw some light on my below answer ? I have provided one answer to this question. Please check that too.

Comment: you can have autoplay with current index with videoref id if equal then play otherwise false

Comment: but how to get current index ?? how to get the index of that video found in the visible view on the screen ???

Comment: You can check doc of that it's provide active screen status